# Find non-printable characters using MS word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-2007

I have written a macro which searches in a word document for a certain wind-card defined text string and then find which paragraph this found match belongs to. Everything works fine, but now I have the following challenge: I need to find non-printable characters, specifically I need to find the Ms word index references, which are show in a word like {XE “text to index”}. 
I found a dilemma, that whilst when I call the Ms Word find dialogue box (CNTRL+F) and then define the wildcard search pattern ‘XE “*”’ then ms Word finds these. However when I pass the same pattern for VBA find function, then it does not find them, so I observe some difference between behavior of manually called Find function and the one from VBA.

Any idea how to find these non-printable characters using VBA?

Just for info, this is how I call find function

`With range1.Find
         .Text = searchString
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
‘some code goes here
   End With`

Comment: check on [THIS SITE](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)

Answer (score 0):

KazJaw, thank you for a link, very informative. 
But, I must say, it did not help in my case. Still the problem which I had is that MS Word Search would produce different results depending on whether it was called manually (CNTRL+F) or from VBA (range.find). The difference is, once again, that manually-called search function finds non-printable index-related characters (provided they are show) but the VBA-called function does not do it.

At certain moment I though that it was fixed, by inserting the line to programmatically show non-printable characters ( `ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = True`).  It was important that it was programmatically, as an opposite to running macro on the document, where it was manually enabled. But even in this case the behaviour was very unstable: it would only work say 1 time out of 10 on exactly the same document. At that moment I must say I thought I was getting crazy because of this instability, but my colleague confirmed that he independently has stumbled across the same issue.

Therefore we concluded that using `range.find` function to search for non-printable characters does not produce a stable result in MS Word.

In our case we reached our goal by searching for indexes (fields objects) directly as an opposite of searching for them as for patterns of non-printable characters

      `For Each aField In range1.Fields

        If aField.Type = 4 Then
            aField.Select
            pageOfFoundIndexEntry = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            textOfFoundIndexEntry = Mid(aField.Code, 4)
...`